# Filtering a set of results obtained from job manager

Tags: programming, qiskit, error-mitigation

I've already generated a filter for readout error mitigation:

```
cal_results = cal_job.result()
meas_fitter = CompleteMeasFitter(cal_results, state_labels)  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
meas_fitter.plot_calibration(ax)
meas_filter = meas_fitter.filter
```

[image]

I have a set of circuits executed using the IBM job manager, the list is called `all_circuits`. After transpling the list, I tried:

```
MExperiments = job_manager.run(all_circuits, backend=backend, shots = nshots)
results = MExperiments.results() 
**mitigated_results = meas_filter.apply(results)**
```

I'm hoping to use the filter to mitigate the errors for each circuit in the list, but the last line doesn't quite work. It shows me

```
QiskitError: 'Unrecognized type for raw_data.'
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks:)

$\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}$

**PS:**
From the [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/noise/3_measurement_error_mitigation.html), there're 4 types of raw data that match the requirement:

Form1: A counts dictionary from results.get_counts,

Form2: A list of counts of length=len(state_labels),

Form3: A list of counts of length=M*len(state_labels) where M is an integer (e.g. for use with the tomography data),

Form4: A qiskit Result.

I'm not pretty sure why the `results` in my code doesn't fit any one of them.

Comment: You can use `type(results)` to find out why `results` doesn't fit any of the four allowed types. This may also give you ideas about how to convert the value to whatever `apply` expects.

Comment: @Adam Zalcman Thank you for the comment! I tried that command and it shows me the type is ```'qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.managedresults.ManagedResults' ```It looks like the parameters for ```apply``` should be a dictionary or list. I'm not pretty sure how I can convert the ```results```

Comment: @Adam Zalcman I just solved the issue. Thanks!!

Comment: Cool! Consider answering your own question. It might help someone in future.

Comment: @Adam Zalcman Sounds good! I'll do that:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, there're 4 types of data that match the requirement. The `results` in this case obtained from the job manager is not the same as the results shown in the tutorial since it contains a set of results from different quantum circuits. (I'm still confused why this is not considered as a qiskit result, i.e Form 4 above.)

As I tried to print the type, it shows me`qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.managedresults.ManagedResults` . Then I searched more information from [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.ManagedResults.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.managed.ManagedResults). There's a method called `combine_results()` that allows us to combine results from all jobs into a single Result, which is the same result in the tutorial's example. So I just did:

```
MExperiments = job_manager.run(all_circuits, backend=backend, shots = nshots)
results = MExperiments.results() 
cresults = results.combine_results()
mitigated_results = meas_filter.apply(cresults)
```

Comment: Ha. I forgot about that there is a combine_result method... I have been loop through all my results and combine them manually... :)

Comment: @KAJ226 Haha thanks!! Yeah I didn't know that, it's really fun to explore the 'method library' :-)

Comment: @KAJ226 Oops.. I just found we might not be able to combine the results if the circuit list gets too large. It shows me ```'Results cannot be combined since some of the jobs failed.'``` In my job status ., however, it shows all the jobs have been successfully executed. Do you know why this happens? -:)

Comment: No, I don't, unfortunately. :(

Comment: @KAJ226 Haha thanks though:)