# Is there a 'retry' logic in job manager?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

This is a follow-up question to my [earlier post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15914/12334). I'm trying to filter a set of results obtained from job manager, and the following code works when my circuit list doesn't contain too many elements:

```
MExperiments = job_manager.run(all_circuits, backend=backend, shots = nshots)
results = MExperiments.results() 
cresults = results.combine_results()
mitigated_results = meas_filter.apply(cresults)
```

The `combine_results()` method is used to help us combine a set of results so that the final single result matches the requirements of `apply`. The prerequisite is that all jobs need to succeed. However, when my list `all_circuits` gets large, it shows me this error message:

```
IBMQManagedResultDataNotAvailable: 'Results cannot be combined since some of the jobs failed.'
```

I checked my job status in IBMQ and it shows all the circuits have been successfully executed. How can I fix this issue? Is there a way I can make the job monitor retry the jobs that failed? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `results = MExperiments.results()`, it should issue a warning message telling you which job result could not be retrieved. The message is only issued for the first `.result()` though, since subsequent calls just use cached data. You can do `results = MExperiments.results(refresh=True)` to force it to re-fetch results from the server (and hence re-issue warning messages). It is possible that the job completed but fetching of the result failed (e.g. due to networking error). `.result(refresh=True)` also serves as a retry mechanism.

Another possibility is that the job submit failed. In which case the job won't show up in IBMQ dashboard. You can use `print(MExperiments.report())` to see which set of circuits doesn't have a successful job.

To answer your last question, job manager today doesn't retry failed jobs (there is an [issue](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/issues/636) open for that though). You can, however, do it manually by

1. use `print(MExperiments.report())` to find out which job failed
2. use `qobj = job.qobj()` to get the qobj and then re-submit it with `new_job = backend.run(qobj)`
3. combine the results yourself and replace the failed job result with the new job result. The report from step 1 tells you the indexes of the experiments that belong to the failed job. Then you can do `result.results[failed_start_index:failed_end_index+1] = new_job.result().results`